# Блок "Лучшие сообщения сети" в профиле

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано

В профиле на ruSO (не меты) в блоке "Лучшие сообщения сети" не отображаются сообщения с ruSO.

Ожидаемое поведение (как в профиле на мете):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текущее поведение (как в профиле на ruSO):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно из последнего скриншота, отображаются сообщения только из enSO.

Comment: Насколько я вижу, мета сообщения вообще не попадают в лучшие сообщения сети. Видимо, так задумано.

Comment: @alexolut понять бы почему сообщения на ruSO не отображаются в профиле на ruSO.

Comment: По той же причине, что в профиле на enSO не отображаются сообщения enSO.

Comment: То есть это так и задумано? Но зачем?!

Comment: Я в ответе указал возможную причину: `Лучшие сообщения текущего сайта отображаются в отдельной секции "Лучшие сообщения/вопросы/ответы" поэтому в блок сообщений сети они не попадают.` В частности, это исключает дублирование информации на странице.

Comment: @alexolut уверен, что отображение русскоязычных сообщений в профиле enSO выглядит для англоязычного пользователя как бессмысленная и бесполезная абракадабра.

Comment: С этим ничего не поделать. Локализованные сообщества в этом плане ничем не отличаются от англоязычных. Ну, и это уже совсем другая история :)

Comment: @alexolut ответ я получил, за это спасибо, но всё ещё уверен, что отображение в этом блоке всех сообщений было бы лучше.

Comment: Основную причину не отображать их я вижу именно в исключении дублирования упоминания одних и тех же сообщений на одной странице. Полный же список лучших сообщений доступен по ссылке на stackexchange.com. С предложением об изменении логики отображения разумнее всего обратиться на [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Блок "Лучшие сообщения сети" при просмотре профиля на сайте Х содержит только сообщения с **других** сайтов. Причем в этот список не попадают сообщения с мета-сайтов. Для таких сообщений есть отдельный блок "Лучшее с Меты". При просмотре же блока с мета-сайта отображаются также сообщения и основного сайта.

Лучшие сообщения текущего сайта отображаются в отдельной секции "Лучшие сообщения/вопросы/ответы" поэтому в блок сообщений сети они не попадают.

Для просмотра полного списка лучших сообщений на всех сайтах (кроме мет) в профиле есть ссылка "[Посмотреть другие сетевые сообщения →](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=top)".

Таким образом, я не вижу здесь какого-либо дефекта вовсе.

Comment: Я видимо плохо формулирую. В моём профиле на ruSO не отображаются сообщения с  ruSO.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev правильно. В профиле основного (не Меты) сайта X в блоке "Лучшие сообщения сети" не отображаются сообщения сайта X.